# Solr document query hits

Tags: solr

I'm trying to find out, if solr have some kind of built-in feature for sorting on document query hits.

Lets say I have a simple document

```
<fields>
  <field name="Id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Tag" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
```

I then have a document where Tag has the value "programming"

When a user is writing "pro" in a search field, I wish to show the tags with prefix "pro" however I wish to sort by query hits, meaning the document which is shown the most.

Example:
Proactive
Problem
Programming
Progress

The programming is the most hit value, however It's not the document shown first.

Does solr have a feature already I can use to archive this? Or do I have to implement it myself?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by most hit value? Does it have the highest score? By default your resultset is sorted by the score of the documents. Can you share the query your are using? Also, the field type definitions would be usefull.

Comment: Lets say the query is q=Tag:"pro*".

By hit value I mean, how many times have a document been returned by a query. If programming has been searched for 100 times and Problem only 70 times, I want programming to be a row 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this but I've found [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Sort-Results-on-Popularity-td4028017.html) post suggesting that Solr does not have an build-in feature for measuring popularity by how many times a document has been returned.

I guess you have to implement it yourself or use one of the existing frameworks, linked in the post I referenced.